# IIS application pool identity permission to isolated storage without changing iis auth method

Tags: c#, .net, iis, openxml, windows-server-2019

We use openxml to generate excel exports. At a certain point when we export too much data we get this error "unable to create mutex". From my research it seems to be because openxml is using isolated storage to cache data on disk because its too big and doesn't have enough permission to write to the isolated storage.

So far ive made research but the only solution ive found referred to changing the auth method of iis app pool which i would prefer not to do. I try to give more permission to the folder i thought iis was trying to save to but without success.

We want to solve the issue without changing the iis app pool auth method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in ApplicationPool's Advanced Settings set Load User Profile to True.

[image]